# How to create a kubernetes client in Go from a Kubeconfig String

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have a secret in my kubernetes cluster which contains a kubeconfig of another Cluster.
I want to be able to connect to that cluster in my Go code.

I only found ways to create a client via a kubeconfig FILE but not with a kubeconfig string.

This is my code so far:

```
    // Read secret
    kubeconfigSecret := &corev1.Secret{}
    err := apiReader.Get(context.Background(), client.ObjectKey{Namespace: namespace, Name: name}, kubeconfigSecret)
    if err != nil {
        // error handling
    }

    kubeconfigBytes, ok := kubeconfigSecret.Data["kubeconfig"]
    if !ok {
        // error handling
    }

    kubeconfigString := string(kubeconfigBytes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways for this purpose, for example:

```golang
content := `a kubeconfig string`
tmpfile, err := os.CreateTemp("", "kubeconfig")
if err != nil {
    ...
}
defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name())
if err := os.WriteFile(tmpfile.Name(), []byte(content), 0666); err != nil {
    ...
}
config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", tmpfile.Name())
if err != nil {
    ...
}

clientset,err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
```

Another way is to use `clientcmd.RESTConfigFromKubeConfig`:

```golang
content := `a kubeconfig string`
config, err := clientcmd.RESTConfigFromKubeConfig([]byte(content))
if err != nil {
    ...
}
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with the `clientcmd.RESTConfigFromKubeConfig` approach.